# Git: reset and checkout in one shot with && doesn't work

Tags: linux, git, version-control

Simple git question. After executing:

```
git reset HEAD file && git checkout -- file
```

The file is still under "Changes not staged for commit" section, but it shouldn't. If I execute the two operations seperately (ie. pressing enter and seeing git status between and after them), it works.

**Platform:** Linux amd64, git version 1.8.1.3

Comment: Strange. Does the checkout actually run (with `&&` the second command will only run if the first succeeds)? What is the exit code of the  `git reset`? Perhaps try to replace `&&` with `;` and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `git reset` returns a non-zero exit code when the file has unstaged commits after the reset.  So the `&&` prevents the `git checkout` from running -- it will only run the second command if the first "succeeds" (i.e. exits with zero).

Answer (score 0):

`git reset HEAD file` just updates the index (i.e., any staged changes to the file are lost), the changed file stays as is.

Why do it this way, if a simple `git checkout file` (perhaps with `-f` if `file` has been changed) acomplishes the same?

Comment: I think you don't get my question right. The two commands makes sense in the mentioned order, and works very well if executed seperately, but doesn't when executed in one line (with &&). This is because of the non-zero return code of git reset.

Comment: @gyabraham, what exactly is the difference to you?